The command prompt does not show java version when I use java -version . I have installed Android Studio Koala. How should I check Java version?
Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install default-jre              # version 2:1.17-75, or
sudo apt install openjdk-17-jre-headless  # version 17.0.10~6ea-1
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless  # version 11.0.21+9-0ubuntu1
sudo apt install openjdk-19-jre-headless  # version 19.0.2+7-4
sudo apt install openjdk-20-jre-headless  # version 20.0.2+9-1
sudo apt install openjdk-21-jre-headless  # version 21.0.1+12-3
sudo apt install openjdk-22-jre-headless  # version 22~22ea-1
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless   # version 8u392-ga-1

This is the result of using java -version command.I am new to Ubuntu and really need help here. A few sites I looked up suggested that Java might be on another path. How should I access this path?

Ubuntu 24.04 LTS is the description. Distributor is Ubuntu. Release is 24.04. Thank you.
